# Displaying newline character in any JTextComponent?

Tags: java, swing, newline, jtextcomponent

How to display newline character in any `JTextComponent` (`JTextArea`, `JTextPane`)?

Comment: I wish that instead of a new line in the editor to appear, for example, an asterisk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guess that's what you need is http://java-sl.com/showpar.html

It shows not only end of par shars but also spaces and tabs.